# Blur a face using only one video layer with Premiere CS6?

Tags: premiere, effects, cs6

so with the new built-in masking option of the gaussian blur and similar effects in the CC version of Premiere Pro it's pretty easy to limit effect to a specific area of the video in order to e.g. blur a face. However, I'm searching for an easy and **easily comprehensible** way to achieve this effect in CS6 without duplicating the clip to a second video layer (video lane?) and using the gaussian blur in combination with a track matte key (which is what I used to do in Premiere Pro CS6).
So, is there a way to blur a face without duplicating the clip to a second video layer in the CS6 version?
(Unfortunately, I only have the current CC version at my disposal right now, so I can't try it out myself at the moment.)
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no, you can do it without duplicating the clip, but not without a second layer.  Instead of using a second copy of the clip, you can use an adjustment layer.  You make a new adjustment layer by creating a New Item in the Project window.  You add that adjustment layer over top of the video you want to adjust and then you apply your masking to the adjustment layer and apply your effects to the adjustment layer.

The effects applied to the adjustment layer are then applied to the sum total of all the layers below the adjustment layer.  Effectively, the adjustment layer is a layer that is composed of a sub-render of everything below it and then has the set of effects applied to it applied to that sub-render.

It technically isn't adding two copies of the sequence, but practically it is still doing the same thing.  I'm not personally aware of any more straightforward technique than that for doing what you describe in CS6 though.  That doesn't necessarily mean much though as I normally do this kind of thing in AE anyway, so my experience doing it in Premiere is limited at best (bordering on non-existent.)

Comment: That's a perfectly viable option for me, thanks :) I didn't want to duplicate the clip, because this frequently led to problems with the cross dissolve transition. Also, I find it couterintuitive and rather confusing for beginners to understand why they need to duplicate the clip. So the adjustment layer is a good solution!

Comment: Another question, how exactly should I mask the adjustment layer? I tried it a few days ago and had some problems, it either didn't work at all (nothing was blurred or everything was blurred) or the mask was applied not to the gaussian blur, but to the video itself, leaving only black space ...